# Link to nonexistent .aspx file works—why?

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, modalpopup

I’ve inherited a DotNetNuke website that shows a modal popup when a “Join Mailing List” hyperlink is clicked: `<a href="/JoinMailingList.aspx" class="JoinMailingList">Join Mailing List</a>`.  However, the website has no JoinMailingList.aspx file.  Yet the link works (though incorrectly: the popup takes up the entire screen instead of appearing “above the fold”).  The link goes to the following jQuery code, but after the popup displays:

```
$(".JoinMailingList").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(".ModalBody .Notification").remove();
    $(".ModalMask").fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    $("#MailingListForm").show("fast");

});
```

Apparently the hyperlink uses the “fake” JoinMailingList.aspx to do the popup, but how?

Comment: You can intercept a click event on anything, and handle it however you wish. (Very commonly preventing regular browser navigation.) This includes a link pointing to anything. This includes a link pointing to a page that doesn't exist. (Not necessarily a good practice though: it'd be best if that page actually did exist, for the mythical "people with Javascript disabled", and for the much less mythical "people who open links in a new tab".)

Comment: Forget the existence of `JoinMailingList.aspx`, it could be `GoHome.aspx` and it would do the same thing. That part of the link is being ignored. All that is happening is the element with `id="MailingListform"` is being shown when that anchor is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

DNN's URL rewriting will look at the name of a page, and try to find a corresponding record in the TABS table. If you need to find that page itself, you can go to the Admin/Page Management page to try and locate it.